# Xamarin Forms : how to change WebView default browser to Microsoft Intune (Company portal) managed browser

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Xamarin Forms : how to change the WebView default browser to Microsoft Intune (Company portal)managed browser. Unbaled to open third-party managed URL using WebView control and Verified in managed device also getting error message as "Set up your device to get access".

Answer (score 0):

Webview uses `Safari`(iOS), `Chrome`(Android),`Edge`(Windows) as default browser , if we load the link on webview , it uses default browser and we can change nothing, however you could take a look at [Xamarin.Essentials: Browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/open-browser?tabs=android), it opens the website outside of the app ,we can choose the external launcher as browser (you should install Edge app first on your device).

```
await Browser.OpenAsync("https://www.google.com", BrowserLaunchMode.External);
```

[image]